# Ruby .each_slice with condition even and odd indexes of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have a Ruby array of the form:

```
array = ["zero","first","second","third"]
```

I want to use a method to split this array into 2 new arrays including the even and odd indexes equivalently.

Ideal result is:

```
newArrayOne = ["zero", "second"]
newArrayTwo = ["first", "third"]
```

using the condition of even or odd index as a boolean.

Note: The array will have many elements.

(for the guy with the rude comment that believes is the best programmer alive)

I tried each_slice which accepta one argument and other methods that their signature did not let me to get what I want.

If the results provided were using that specific method in question title, say whatever you like!!!

I was not aware of the methods suggested in the comments and answers, this is why I posted and I am not learning Ruby or using Ruby, I just had to do work of other people absent. Happy now?

Comment: `["zero","first","second","third"].group_by.with_index { |x,i| i % 2 }.values
#=> [["zero", "second"], ["first", "third"]]`

Comment: thank you, but, can we have two different one dimensional arrays?

Comment: `newArrayOne, newArrayTwo = ["zero","first","second","third"].group_by.with_index { |x,i| i % 2 }.values`

Comment: You can get `[0]` / `first` and `[1]` / `last` mate

Comment: We'd like to know what you tried to solve this. Please read "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. Without that evidence of effort it really looks like you're asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: If `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, do you want `[[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]` or `[[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]`? An example with more than four elements would have been better unless, of course, you are only concerned about arrays of size four. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: @theTinMan I tried each_slice which accepta one argument and other methods that their signature did not let me to get what I want.  If the results provided were using that specific method in question title, say whatever you like!!!  I was not aware of the methods suggested in the comments and answers, this is why I posted and I am not learning Ruby or using Ruby, I just had to do work of other people absent.

Comment: Please stop sniping at each other in the comments. Comments are *not* for extended discussion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
newArrayOne, newArrayTwo = array.partition.with_index { |_,i| i.even? }
```

Comment: Very smart usage of [`Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)!

Comment: This appears identical to @mudasobwa's answer posted three minutes earlier. I don't doubt that you came up it independently, but have you added anything new?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I believe timstott introduced parallel assignment in his answer which mudasobwa's answer did not originally include. I upvoted both answers.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, I see, and wasn't aware of that. I'd think the parallel assignment was obvious, but perhaps not to all readers. OK, upvote.

Answer (score 5):

```
["zero","first","second","third"].partition.with_index { |_, i| i.even? }
#⇒ [["zero", "second"], ["first", "third"]]

newArrayOne, newArrayTwo = ["zero","first","second","third"]
                             .partition
                             .with_index { |_, i| i.even? }

newArrayOne
#⇒ ["zero", "second"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
newArrayOne, newArrayTwo = ["zero","first","second","third"]
                             .each_slice(2)
                             .to_a
                             .transpose
```

or

```
newArrayOne, newArrayTwo = Hash["zero","first","second","third"]
                             .to_a
                             .transpose
```

or:

```
["zero","first","second","third"].each_with_object([[], []]) do |e, acc|
  (acc.first.length <= acc.last.length ? acc[0] : acc[1]) << e
end
```

and, of course, using [flip-flop](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/) (my fave):

```
["zero","first","second","third"].each_with_object([[], []]) do |e, acc|
  flipflop = acc.first.size == acc.last.size
  (flipflop..flipflop ? acc[0] : acc[1]) << e
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that, if `n = array.size`, an array of `n/2` elements is to be returned. See my comment on the question.

```
array = %w| zero first second third fourth fifth |
  #=> ["zero", "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]

newArrayOne, newArrayTwo = array.each_slice(array.size/2).to_a.transpose
  #=> [["zero", "third"], ["first", "fourth"], ["second", "fifth"]]
```

If, however, the array always has exactly four elements:

```
newArrayOne, newArrayTwo = [[array[0], array[2]], [array[1], array[3]]]
  #=> [["zero", "second"], ["first", "third"]]
```

Comment: `["zero","first","second","third"].partition { |w| w.length.even? }` :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the comments provided by @bjhaid

```
["zero","first","second","third"].group_by.with_index { |x,i| i % 2 }.values
#=> [["zero", "second"], ["first", "third"]]
```